# Dataservices not getting executed in WSO2 ESB 5.0.0 tenants

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have couple of dataservices to be run on wso2 esb. I have created a tenant instance and placed these dataservices in `repository/tenants/[tenant_id]/dataservices`. when I login into wso2 management console with tenant user and try to run any of the dataservice- I’m getting an error saying

> the input stream of an incoming message is null

On the other hand the dataservices placed for the master user under folder `repository/deployment/server/dataserivice` is getting executed and fetching desired results when ran through admin master user. can I get some help to resolve this issue with tenant.

Comment: The dataservice is giving results through rest client where as there is no result when accessed through soap client. Is there any specific configuration to be done?